# WPF RibbonComboBox scroll bar / limit number of items

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ribbon

I'm having problems with the RibbonComboBox in WPF. I have a list with a lot of items I want to add. There are too many items to fit into the window and so you can't see every item. This wouldn't be too bad, but the problem is that there is no scroll bar. I can scroll with the keyboard and the cursor then goes missing until I reach the end of the list and then I'm back on the top of the list.
Is there a way to
a) have a scrollbar
b) limit the number of elements that are shown when the dropdown button is clicked (I know it works for the regular combobox)?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Best wishes
C

Comment: Try adding a ScrollViewer in its style. Preferably as ContentControl

Comment: How would I go about doing that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements *can* be achieved, but unfortunately, it will be a very painful procedure. The reason why the `RibbonComboBox` does not have a `ScrollBar` is because whoever developed it did a really poor job. Apparently, the default `ControlTemplate` uses a `StackPanel` internally, which as we all know is totally useless for these kinds of sizing issues.

As more items are added, the `StackPanel` just lets the `ItemsPresenter` grow infinitely. You can find a bit of a description of this in the [RibbonComboBox does not display a scroll bar when appropriate](http://odyssey.codeplex.com/workitem/5776) page on CodePlex.

Therefore the fix is for you to declare a new `ControlTemplate` based on the default one and to replace this `StackPanel` with a `Grid`, or `DockPanel` as the linked page advises (although I personally think that a `DockPanel` might be a bit expensive for this task).

So how do you get the default `ControlTemplate` to base yours upon? Well, Microsoft have also made that more difficult by *not* providing it along with all of there other controls in the [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pages on MSDN. Instead, you can use `Blend` to find it and you can get help with that task by reading the [Blend tip: finding default styles using “Edit a Copy”](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/using-blend-to-find-default-style-xaml/) page on Jeff Wilcox's website.

Good luck.

Comment: Wow, that really does sound painful :) Thanks so much. Now at least I know where I'm at. I've tried it with a regular ComboBox and this works just fine, so maybe I'll just stick with that (although it doesn't look too good).
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Set the veritcal scroll bar visibility to auto: `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`

```
                <RibbonComboBox Name="Types" SelectionBoxWidth="100">
                    <RibbonGallery Name="RibbonCombobox" MaxColumnCount="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <RibbonGalleryCategory Name="UserBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                            <RibbonGalleryItem IsSelected="True">Item 1</RibbonGalleryItem>
                            <RibbonGalleryItem>Item 2</RibbonGalleryItem>
                            <RibbonGalleryItem>Item 3</RibbonGalleryItem>
                        </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    </RibbonGallery>
                </RibbonComboBox>
```

Comment: ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" is your answer